# Identify duplicate values and remove them

Tags: r, diff, shift

I have a vector:

```
vec <- c(2,3,5,5,5,5,6,1,9,4,4,4)
```

I want to check if a particular value is repeated consecutively and if yes, keep the first two values and assign `NA` to the rest of the values.

For example, in the above vector, 5 is repeated 4 times, therefore I will keep the first two 5's and make the second two 5's NA.
Similarly, 4 is repeated three times, so I will keep the first two 4's and remove the third one.

In the end my vector should look like:

```
2,3,5,5,NA,NA,6,1,9,4,4,NA
```

I did this:

```
bad.values <- vec - binhf::shift(vec, 1, dir="right") 
bad.repeat <- bad.values == 0

vec[bad.repeat] <- NA

[1]  2  3  5 NA NA NA  6  1  9  4 NA NA
```

I can only get it to work to keep the first 5 and 4 (rather than first two 5's or 4',4's).

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option with just base R functions:

```
rl <- rle(vec)

i <- unlist(lapply(rl$lengths, function(l) if (l > 2) c(FALSE,FALSE,rep(TRUE, l - 2)) else rep(FALSE, l)))

vec * NA^i
```

which gives:

> ```
>   [1]  2  3  5  5 NA NA  6  1  9  4  4 NA
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to change the argument to 2 in binhf::shift

```
vec <- c(2,3,5,5,5,5,6,1,9,4,4,4)
bad.values <- vec - binhf::shift(vec, 2, dir="right") 
bad.repeat <- bad.values == 0
vec[bad.repeat] <- NA

[1]  2  3  5  5 NA NA  6  1  9  4  4 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work, if I got your problem right:

```
vec <- c(2,3,5,5,5,5,6,1,9,4,4,4)
diffs1<-vec-binhf::shift(vec,1,dir="right")
diffs2<-vec-binhf::shift(vec,2,dir="right")
get_zeros<-abs(diffs1)+abs(diffs2)
vec[which(get_zeros==0)]<-NA
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

This question may refer to a problem you encountered in a dataframe, not a vector. In any case, here's a tidyverse solution to both.

```
tibble(x = vec) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>%   
  mutate(mycol = ifelse(row_number()>2, NA, x) ) %>% 
  pull(mycol)
```